# What is the cause of this problem "IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection" on Sql Developer?

Tags: oracle, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

I make a connection for connect to the Database Server (other machine).
Then I found "An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
Vendor code 17002".

Please look the picture in URL below.

[image: error message]

I tried to make a connection but can't access but my team can access it.
My friend used TNS connection type and I did everthing similar him but can't access. I tried to use JDBC thin for connect but can't also.

I had the old connection which I can connect but why I can't connect the new connection.

Comment: Can you show us the code that connects?

Comment: @deHaar I used GUI for make a connection, Do you need  the capture ?

Comment: Do you mean this is not about Java code? Don't you have the Java code that tries to connect?

Comment: Yes,I'm not. No, I'm not. Just GUI on sql developer.

Comment: Well, since the message is talking about a *Network Adapter*, I guess you have to check the LAN connectivity of the computer you are using.

Comment: I double checked already about LAN cable, I can ping to that mchine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to connect to a machine on a network that SQL Developer is unable to reach.

For a TNS connection, 
Look at the appropriate TNSNames entry (you will have a tnsnames.ora) file, and find the IP address or network name associated with the connection you're trying to establish -

[image]
And then start by trying to ping that resource.

In this case, i'm trying to talk to a database on MY machine, on port 1521. Yours should look quite different.

If you're using a basic connection, then you can look at the connection properties and see what machine/port you're trying to communicate with.

[Ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility))

[image]

If you can't reach that machine from your machine, there's zero chance you can connect to a database there.

So, always start with a ping.

Once you see that you can get to that machine, if you're still getting that message, the next thing to think about is blocked ports, the listener defaults to port 1521, but you'll see that in the TNS descriptor as well.

Comment: I can ping to that machine. Is it possible my machine has been block or something like that ? Because my team can connect normally but can't connect only me laptop. I tried to fix this for 2 day ago.

Comment: Are you on the same network as your team? Yes, it's possible the listener port is protected by a firewall

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Thank you, Jeff. +1. I have allowed my ports by rules in the firewall. And still, I have no connection to host/port by telnet.  Can something else prevent me from connecting? My remote host should be connected by VPN. And I can ping to it.

Comment: you'll get the same error if your PORT number is wrong. say i have the listener running on port 1521, but in my connection i put 1522 - it has the same effect. Make sure your port is correct

Answer (score 1):

It usually happens when a another process is running on the same port or there is an absence of listener.

Go to Run>services.msc>OracleXETNSListener>Start

Try to reconnect.. Even if the error still prevail then go to cmd
Use code:

```
npx kill-port <portnumber>
```

The port number by default is 1521, but you can check the port number in database properties.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, that your connection is forbidden by the firewall -

go to Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall - Advanced - Outbound Rules - Add a rule. (If you have some antivirus firewall, add rules there)

Create a temporary TCP rule for your port and another rule for UDP. Allow all nets and comps.

Check the telnet connection as cmd -> telnet ->

```
open remote.host.address PortNumber
```

If you can connect now, then the problem IS in firewall - edit your new rules, setting the hosts and nets exactly.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because your sqldeveloper is not able to reach the database server's sql service.

One reason could be `lsnrctl` is down for some reason.
If you have access to machine where database is installed.

In Windows machine, follow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9pHqOfV2f0&ab_channel=TLinaTutorials

In Linux/macOS machine: Go to `$ORACLE_HOME/bin` and check status of `lsnrctl`
execute from `$ORACLE_HOME/bin` `lsnrctl status`, if it's down. Then restart it by `lsnrctl start`.

Check the details of connection in command output like `SID`, `PORT`, `HOST` etc. and try connecting again from sqldeveloper.